# Xamarin Form : Master Detail Page : How to disable swipe gesture to load the menu on iOS

Tags: ios, menu, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I need the screen to draw stuff on it. Since I have a Master Detail Page on the same screen, whenever I draw in a direction as opening the menu, the menu will swipe open at the same time as I draw.

Is there a way to stop it from swipe open, but still have the menu button clickable to open it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
#if __IOS__
    IsGestureEnabled = false
#endif
```

Setting Is GestureEnabled to false will stop from the menu being swiped open. This value only can be set for iOS. If I set for android, the menu button will not open the menu when clicked.

Comment: You can mark your reply as an answer - there's nothing wrong in such practice and this will definitely help others

Comment: Ever figure out a solution for Android to accomplish this?  Seems silly this isn't easy.

Comment: Does anyone know a way to do the same effect on xamarin android as well?

Answer (score 3):

For this, you need to write IsPresented = true along with

```
#if __IOS__
IsGestureEnabled = false
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

On `MasterDetailPage` you add this:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
    {
        IsGestureEnabled = false;
    }
}
```