# Community Toolkit Drawing View interfering with navigation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, maui

I am trying to use the DrawingView from the Community Toolkit in my app, but it doesn't work well with the Flyout/MasterDetail page.

As you can see in the images below, while I'm trying to add a signature, the signature doesn't go beyond a certain point and instead pulls the flyout menu out.

And the point the flyout menu gets dragged out is dependent on where you start the signature. Is there a workaround this issue?

Alternatively, I could temporarily disable the iOS behavior that opens the flyout menu when you swipe right across the screen [using this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515952/xamarin-form-master-detail-page-how-to-disable-swipe-gesture-to-load-the-men)

[image: Attempt 1]

[image: Attempt 2]

Comment: When the Drawing event is triggered disable the FlyoutMenu and when the completed event is triggered enable it

Comment: can you provide the code about the signature and flyout menu?